# Distribution of tests on Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have been using Microsoft Test Manager for a long time. I have configured SCVMM lab with 3 web client machines that I use to run my tests.

Everything works fine, except for 1 issue: I have almost 350 tests. When I run all of then or even a small part they are divided across the 3 web client machines. But some tests take more time that others. Because of this, some machines finish their work fast but the others machines continue to get more tests to execute.

This is what I mean:

- I fire 300 tests to be executed by 3 machines
- Every machine gets 100 tests to execute
- The machine 1 and 2 gets the job done fast
- The machine 3 executes 80 tests and continues until it finishes.

My question is: Is there any way of optimizing this so no machine will be idle when other machines are working yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into changing the `BucketSize` in your test settings. Unfortunately I don't think this is supported as standard and you will have to use a utility that can be found and explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2010/08/11/how-to-run-automated-tests-on-different-machines-in-parallel.aspx). If you reduce the bucket size to something like 25, then when the faster machines finish their current bucket the Test Controller will assign a new one while the slower machine still works on its current bucket.
 
I assume this should work for you, though the utility is not supported and I have not tried it myself for bucketsize previously.

Comment: I already tested this app and it does not seen to work as intended. I have no idea why...

Comment: So you tried altering the BucketSize and the change did not occur? Or did you successfully change the BucketSize and the tests were not run more efficiently?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What did happen? Was it that the amount of tests queued at a time did not change, or that they did change but the machines still were chosen sub-optimally?

Comment: They did change (or at least is what the app told me) but the machines still where chosen sub-optimally. It seams to me that the change was not really applied.

Comment: Are all the machines in the one Lab Management Environment? You must ensure that the testsetting file has the new value and that you are in fact using that testsetting file. If all of this has been done (as it sounds), I would suggest posting a separate question explaining that the BucketSize has been changed and yet the default BucketSize of 100 is still being used.